# Laravel FirstOrCreate Method returned Column not found

Tags: laravel

I am trying to check if data exist in a table before saving. I can save to the table

```
 public function read($book_id)
 {

        MyBook::create([
            'book_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]);
    $readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get()->first();
    return view('read')->with('data', $readBooks);
}
```

But when I tried to use firstOrCreate to check before  saving it returned this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `my_books` where (`1` is null and `1` is
>   null) limit 1)

This is the method I am using

```
 public function read($book_id)
 {

    $mybook = MyBook::firstOrCreate([
        ['book_id' => $book_id],
        ['user_id' => Auth::id()]
    ]);
    $readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get()->first();
    return view('read')->with('data', $readBooks);
}
```

My `my_book` table schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('my_books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I hope I can find help here.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing array inside it also  2 array. But that is not correct. You must be use like this

```
$mybook = MyBook::firstOrCreate(
    ['book_id' => $book_id],
    ['user_id' => Auth::id()]
);
```

Comment: I glade help you

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a single array of arrays as the first argument to `firstOrCreate`. It takes associative arrays for the arguments.

```
$mybook = MyBook::firstOrCreate(
    ['book_id' => $book_id],
    ['user_id' => Auth::id()]
);
```

Argument 1 and 2 are associative arrays.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Other Creation Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods) `firstOrCreate`